Equivalent inductance seen from a winding
I would be having a little trouble understanding how to do this problem of magnetic circuits. It asks me to calculate the equivalent inductance seen from winding N2. I know how to calculate the inductance of each winding on its own. Making L=N^2/R(total). (For R(tot) I do:
R1 + (R3+R1)*R3/(R3+R1+R3))
But I don't understand what they're asking of me. I interpreted it as starting from the point where winding N2 is, then what I have just to the right would be winding N3, therefore I think that I only need to calculate the inductance of N3, in the way I already mentioned .
I only invented the data to illustrate that the values ​​are not necessarily equal (Honestly, I am not very interested in the numerical issue, but rather in interpreting what I should do.
)
Is it okay the way I interpret it? Or what am I doing wrong? What do you think?

Pd:if I want to calculate the total inductance, would it simply be the sum of the 3 inductances, that is, the inductances of each winding?

Is there a typo in your formula? Surely the second term would contain R2 and R3. Could you label which branches are which reluctances in the figure? How are you expressing the airgap? Have you drawn the equivalent (sources and resistors) circuit?
